# MongoMemoryReplSet from mongodb-memory-server with jest throws open handle Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs

Running the test file throws following error:

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests.
Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

```
"jest": "^26.4.2",
"mongodb-memory-server": "^6.9.2",
```

Requiring replset from `mongodb-memory-server`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { MongoMemoryReplSet } = require('mongodb-memory-server');

const replSet = new MongoMemoryReplSet({
    replSet: { storageEngine: 'wiredTiger' },
});
```

Initialise DB:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    await replSet.waitUntilRunning();
    const uri = await replSet.getUri();
    await mongoose.connect(uri,
        {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useFindAndModify: false
        }, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                process.exit(1);
            }
        });
    await new User(testUser).save();
});
```

TearDown:

```
afterAll(async()=>{
    await mongoose.connection.close();
    await replSet.stop()
})
```

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: @VytautasPranskunas nope, for the time being we decided to remove that test case

Comment: I was able to fix my all tests.. spent 10 hours in order to find recepe for whole setup including migrations... But yours looks simple and should not be throwing that... Try running htis comand - it might help: node --trace-warnings node_modules/.bin/jest